# Hartl Tutorial: Can't Figure Out How To Fix This 1 Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am finishing the book and I've ignored this error message for too long. Please help me understand how to fix this. Thank you!

1) Error:
PasswordResetsTest#test_password_resets:
NoMethodError: undefined method `reset_sent_at=' for #<User:0x007f814e118600>
    app/models/user.rb:63:in`create_reset_digest'
    app/controllers/password_resets_controller.rb:12:in `create'
    test/integration/password_resets_test.rb:17:in`block in '

Comment: Could you give your code at that point in the test, model, and the controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error might point you a little bit into the wrong direction. This `NoMethodError` is actually caused by that fact that your `users` table doesn't have a column `reset_sent_at`.

Rails defines accessor methods (getters and setters) on your `User` model for each column in the `users` table. However, since it doesn't have a `reset_sent_at` column, no accessor is defined and the `NoMethodError` is being raised.

Make sure you've created the migration where `reset_sent_at` was added to `users` (this was done in [chapter 10 of the Rails tutorial](https://www.railstutorial.org/book/account_activation_password_reset)), and that you have executed the migration as well. After the migration, be sure to restart your Rails server.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! I tried manually adding the reset_sent_at into the db schema.rb file, but it didn't work. Then I forced: $ rails generate migration add_reset_to_users reset_digest:string \
> reset_sent_at:datetime

Comment: Now when I try the bundle exec rake db:migrate it doesnt work and I get a long error message that includes this at the start:

Comment: ** Invoke db:migrate (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
** Invoke db:load_config (first_time)
** Execute db:load_config
** Execute db:migrate
== 20141214204411 AddResetToUsers: migrating ===========================
-- add_column(:users, :reset_digest, :string)
rake aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:
SQLite3::SQLException: duplicate column name: reset_digest: ALTER TABLE "users" ADD "reset_digest" varchar/Users/galli01anthony/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4/gems/sqlite3-1.3.9/lib/sqlite3/database.rb:91:in `initialize'

Comment: So the other column already exists. You may have forgotten only  the `reset_sent_at` in the migration. Best thing to do is to look in the old migration to see if you did forget the one column, or if something else went wrong.