# NoMethodError: undefined method reset_sent_at hartle tutorial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, railstutorial.org, nomethoderror

I'm doing chapter 10 of [enter link description here](https://www.railstutorial.org/book/account_activation_password_reset#code-password_reset_update_action/). I got the same error mentioned in [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27464408/hartl-tutorial-cant-figure-out-how-to-fix-this-1-error/%22this%20question%22)

```
    PasswordResetsTest#test_password_resets:
NoMethodError: undefined method `reset_sent_at=' for #<User:0xccd47c0>
    app/models/user.rb:66:in `create_reset_digest'
    app/controllers/password_resets_controller.rb:12:in `create'
    test/integration/password_resets_test.rb:17:in `block in <class:PasswordResetsTest>'
```

I try to do everything mentioned in the answer.
first thing I did was:

```
rails generate migration add_reset_to_users reset_digest:string reset_sent_at:datetime
```

and the answer was:

```
Another migration is already named add_reset_to_users:
```

so I'm sure I did the migration before.
This _add_reset_to_users.rb file in migrate folder.

```
class AddResetToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :users, :reset_digest, :string
  end
end
```

Then I try to restart my rails server.(I'm not sure if I'm doing it right) using

```
rails server
```

and then shutting down the server.
Non of them worked. I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: Have you run the database migration `$ rake db:migrate`? It should give no output if there are no pending migrations. Also check the migration file in `db/migrations` where the file name ends with `add_reset_to_users.rb`.

Comment: Yes, I added it in my post.  rake db:migrate give me no output.

Comment: Try `rake db:test:prepare`, it will give a depreciation warning but I´ve sometimes found that Rails fails to maintain the test schema automatically

Comment: It give me no output! What does it mean?
Am I using a correct way to restart rails server?

Comment: Your tests don't actually run on your `rails server` instance - instead the tests start a rails instance which connects to the test database (as defined in `config/database.yml`). You can test if this is test only issue by starting the console `rails c`. The console uses the development database - the same db as development server (`rails server`). Try something like `User.first.reset_sent_at`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Another migration is already named add_reset_to_users:

You had already created the migration previously, as you noted, but this migration did not include the addition of the `reset_sent_at` column.

At this point the easiest thing to do would be to create a new migration to add the missing column.

```
rails generate migration add_reset_sent_at_to_users reset_sent_at:datetime
```